# JPA query order by comparison of local column and joined table column?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

Suppose I have two tables : `Topic` and `Post` .

`Topic` has `@OneToMany Set<Post> posts` which means one topic may have zero or many replied posts. ( And `Post` has an `@ManyToOne Topic topic` link back to `Topic` )

Both `Topic` and `Post` have a `created` column , storing timestamp.

I want to get **a list of topic order by latest replied post time , if one topic has no post replied , it will judge from topic's created time**.

Such pseudo JPQL may look like :

```
select t from Topic t left outer join t.posts p 
order by "max(t.created , latest p.created if p exists)" desc
group by t.id
```

Of course it won't work because I don't know how to write the correct `order by` clause here.

Can someone give me a hint ? Thanks.

==================== Updated ====================

Thanks to @Utsav SQL example . And this is the working JPQL :

```
select t 
from Topic t
left outer join t.posts p
group by t.id 
order by  (case when p.id is null then t.created else max(p.created) end ) desc
```

And I am facing the problem of this :

```
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
'DBNAME.p.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

This seems something incompatible with MySQL 5.7.x+ with OS/X 10.11 (Yosemite) . My working solution is here [Getting this SQL Error: GROUP BY incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12519)

After modifying `my.cnf` and restart MySQL , it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added group by logic.

I am assuming that `posts` table has a `tid` column which references to `topic.id`.

```
select t.id,
    case when p.id is null 
        then t.created
        else max(p.created) 
    end 
as derived_max_time
From topic t
left join posts p
on t.id=p.tid
group by t.id
order by derived_max_time desc
```

**See Updated MYSQL fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abbfb/8

Comment: Hi , how to group by topic ? demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc6b/3 . There will be duplicated topic listed (because it links to 2 posts).

Comment: So in case a topic is linked to multiple posts, you need only the latest post created date right?

Comment: Yes , if the topic has posts , it grabs the latest replied post time . If the topic has no posts , it checks itself created time .  Order by the two time.

Comment: SQLFiddle seems ok , but when running in mysql , I am facing mysql error 1055 : `Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'DBNAME.p.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` ... not sure where goes wrong.